# Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, ng-bootstrap

I added the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.23 library in **package.json** under dependencies.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.23",
"aes": "0.1.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",

"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"ng2-appinsights": "^0.3.0",
"applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.8",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"zone.js": "^0.7.4"
},
```

And also added the below in **system.js.config.js** file

```
'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
```

**system.js.config.js**

```
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
  'ng2-bootstrap': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap',
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
  'cryptojs':                  'npm:crypto-js/crypto-js.js',
  'ng2-appinsights': 'npm:ng2-appinsights',
  'applicationinsights-js': 'npm:applicationinsights-js'
},
```

After configured everything and run my Angular2 application, it gives error like below figure.

[image]

How can I resolve the above error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this.Refer the path to 'node_modules' folder it will resolve the issue.

```
 '@ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap',
 '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
```

or

```
 // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': {main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}

  };
```

Comment: I tried with above lines of code but still I am getting same error. in my code npm means 'node_modules/'

Comment: '@ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap',
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'  Place this code and check it

Answer (score 0):

I added the below two lines of code in **system.js.config.js**

```
 '@ng-bootstrap':'npm:@ng-bootstrap',
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
```

And updated the **node.js** to 6.10.2 because the @ng-bootstrap module will work only on this version of node.js.

if you want more information about @ng-bootstrap library, please see the below link.

[ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/package.json)